# Woocommerce WordPress Emails + WP Mail SMTP + mailgun + @yahoo.com & @outlook.com = SPAM

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, smtp, mailgun

I'm using mailgun and the WP Mail SMTP plugin to send out transactional email from woocommerce shop.
On mailgun I'm on a shared server.

I've sent out some test emails and unfortunately it seems that customers with email addresses @yahoo.com and outlook.com will find my emails only in their SPAM / JUNK folder.

@gmail and @gmx seems to work (INBOX)

Do you face this issue as well or did I set up something wrong?
Is it because I'm on a shared mailgun IP?

I've read somewhere that you can try to "delete" your mailgun IP under "Manage IP" and get a new one. Is this correct? Will this possibly solve the problem?

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you've not done so already, make sure to do the [Mailgun domain verification](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain). You can also check two tools to see if there's anything you need to fix on your end before trying for a new IP:

1. [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/)
2. [Mail Tester](https://www.mail-tester.com/) (just using WP Mail SMTP's test email function to the address they generate for you)

But if those show up clean (or if they imply your mail server has a bad reputation), I'd try the new IP.